# Programming Sieve of Eratosthenes and Writing to a file

Tags: java, primes

So I have an assignment where we have to generate all the primes between 0 a user-determined value less than 200 using the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, and then write those primes to a file called "primesTo200.txt" with a maximum of 10 prime numbers per line. Now my code works perfectly fine when I enter 120 as the maximum prime value, but when I try to enter any other number between 0-200, it will generate the primes fine but I get an "out of bounds exception" error when it tries to write to the file. Why is that?? I haven't hard-coded anything that would make only 120 work... could someone help me please?? ^_^

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class A1Q1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a maximum value up to which you wish to generate prime numbers [max 200]: ");
    int maxValue = keyboard.nextInt();

    while(maxValue > 200 || maxValue < 0)
    {
      System.out.println("Sorry, that is not a max value between [0 - 200]. Please enter another integer: ");
      maxValue = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    int[] primes = generatePrimes(maxValue);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primes));

    try
    {
      FileWriter fileName = new FileWriter("primesTo200.txt.");
      recordArray(primes, fileName);
    }

    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  public static int[] generatePrimes(int maxValue)
  {
    boolean[] array = new boolean[maxValue + 1];
    int[] primesFull = new int[maxValue];
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i < array.length; i++)
    {
      array[i] = true;
    }

    for(int nextPrime = 2; nextPrime * nextPrime <= maxValue; nextPrime++)
    {
      for(int i = 2; i * nextPrime <= maxValue; i++)
      {
        array[i * nextPrime] = false;
      }
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= maxValue; i++)
    {
      if(array[i] == true)
      {
        primesFull[count] = i;
        count++;
      }
    }

    int[] primes = new int[count];
    System.arraycopy(primesFull, 0, primes, 0, count);

    return primes;
  }


  public static void recordArray(int[] primes, FileWriter fileName)
  {
    PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    int lineLength = 10;
    int count = 0;

    while(count < primes.length)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++)
      {
        fileOut.print(primes[count] + " ");
        count++;
      }
      fileOut.print("\n");
    }

    fileOut.close();
    System.out.println("Program wrote to the file successfully.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++)` is the problem.

You're going through 10 primes every time your outer loop iterates (and skipping checks of `count < primes.length`), regardless of whether or not you have 10 primes left to print into your file

Comment: Oooooooh great thanks!! Do you have a recommendation then about how I go about making it so that it still only writes 10 integers to a line, but if there are less then it will still write them without going out of bounds? Is there an exception I could throw/catch?

Comment: Instead of writing an inner loop, trying using an if statement checking if your counter is divisible by 10 (and not zero).  If it is, then tack on a '\n' into the file at that point.  There might be slicker solutions, but this'll get the job done.